# Why does creating a pointer to a node on the stack cause my linked list display function to go in an infinite loop after two insertions?

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list

I'm learning about linked lists and am trying to understand why the "new" operator is used when inserting a node in the linked list. Specifically I am wondering why the following implementation of insertAtEnd results in an infinite loop when calling display() after two or more insertAtEnd calls.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node {
    public:
        int data;
        Node* next;
        Node() {
            data = 0;
            next = NULL;
        }
        Node(int x) {
            data = x;
            next = NULL;
        }
};

class LinkedList {
    private:
        Node* head;
    public:
        LinkedList() {
            head = NULL;
        }

        // insert a node at the end of the linked list
        void insertAtEnd(int x) {
            Node newNode = Node(x);
            Node* current = head;
            // if LL is empty
            if (head == NULL) {
                head = &newNode;
            }
            // if LL is non-empty
            else {
                while (current->next != NULL) {
                    current = current->next;
                    
                }
                current->next = &newNode;
            }
        }

        // print out the contents of the linked list
        void display() {
            Node* current = head;
            while (current != NULL) {
                cout << current->data << " ";
                current = current->next;
            }
            cout << endl;
        }


};

int main() {
    LinkedList llist;
    llist.insertAtEnd(1);
    llist.insertAtEnd(2); 
    llist.insertAtEnd(3); 
    llist.display();

    return 0;
}
// output shows 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 .....
```

I know that using the new operator would fix the issue,

```
        // insert a node at the end of the linked list
        void insertAtEnd(int x) {
            Node* newNode = new Node(x);
            Node* current = head;
            // if LL is empty
            if (head == NULL) {
                head = newNode;
            }
            // if LL is non-empty
            else {
                while (current->next != NULL) {
                    current = current->next;
                    
                }
                current->next = newNode;
            }
        }
```

but I'm having difficulty understanding why using new here works and why the previous insertAtEnd, which doesn't use new, doesn't work.

My understanding is if new is used, additional memory is dynamically allocated on the heap (different memory location) each time I call insertAtEnd. If new isn't used, then insertAtEnd creates a node object on the stack each time its called, which is in the same memory location, causing the values inserted to overwrite the previously inserted values. But I'm not sure why the output is 3 3 3 3 3... rather than 1 2 3 or just 3 if using the insertAtEnd implementation without new.

Comment: What has your teacher told you about new (and delete) and where objects are created? Losely speaking without new your object is allocated on the stack (and will be deleted when you leave the function) and with new your Node will be allocated in memory (heap) and will stay "alive" until you call delete. Small side note : replace `NULL` with `nullptr`

Comment: If the object is allocated on the stack and goes out of scope, it gets deleted. But I'm also wondering if the object is deleted, then why does calling ll.display() show the previously inserted node containing vaue 3, if it was deleted automatically when going out of scope?

Comment: @Patty12345 -- Your first `insertAtEnd` will lead to undefined behavior since you are storing the address of a local variable.  That local variable is no longer valid.  I ran your code using Visual C++ 2022 in debug mode, and got this as output: `2082743487 1224904152`

Comment: Creating an object on the stack is like drinking from a glass when you're at your friend's house.   You don't get to take it with you when you leave and it won't have the same drink in it if you come back another day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that after leaving a function (e.g., `llist.insertAtEnd`), the stack area will be reused by later function calls (e.g., `llist.display`), thus possibly overwriting previously used values. Also, different compilers may used different orderings of values on the stack. As such, the behavior will depend on things like which compiler you're using, so it's UB (Undefined Behavior).

Nonetheless, here's what is basically happening in your case. During each call to `insertAtEnd`, the constructor is invoked for your `newNode` object on the stack, so `data` is set to `x` (i.e., 1, 2 or 3), and `next` is set to `NULL`. After the function ends, since you have not created a `Node` destructor, the default one is invoked instead, with it not doing *anything* in your case, so the values of `data` and `next` are left unchanged.

Also, during the first call, the value of `head` is NULL, so `head` is assigned to point at your `newNode` object on the stack. For the second and third calls, since `head` is not `NULL`, it will check `current`, i.e., `head`, which is pointing to `newNode`. Since the constructor set that to `NULL`, the line `current->next = &newNode;` sets it to point to `newNode`. In other words, at that point, `newNode.next` is pointing to itself.

Since this is not changed on exit, this is what is left being used, i.e., the `next` pointer is pointing to its own object. Also, on the third call, the value of `newNode.data` is 3. Thus, `llist.display();` goes into an infinite loop (since `current->next` always points back to itself, it will never be NULL), repeatedly outputting the value of 3.

The reason `new` works properly instead is that, on each call to `llist.insertAtEnd`, a *different* area of memory is used for the `Node` object, so the issues mentioned above don't apply then.

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications. I am wondering about the part "current->next always points back to itself, it will never be NULL". I understand this part, but when I modified the while loop in the else,              `   while (current->next != NULL) {
                    cout << "while in else was executed" << endl;
                    current = current->next;
                    
                }     `        the cout statement never gets printed meaning that current->next is NULL

Comment: @Patty12345 You're welcome. At the while loop in the else, the `Node` constructor for `newNode` had been called so it has set `newNode.next` to be NULL. Since `current` is pointing to `&newNode`, then  `current->next` actually *is* NULL then, so the `while` loop is not executed. Thus, you are correct about that. However, the next line after the loop, i.e., `current->next = &newNode;`, is where that issue arises since it sets the `Node` object that `current` is pointing to, i.e., `newNode`, to have its `next` value pointing back to itself. If this is still not clear, I suggest perhaps ...

Comment: @Patty12345 (cont.) using a debugger. However, as what you're doing is "undefined behavior", compiling in debug mode and using a debugger may cause different results to occur (including even crashing), such as suggested in [PaulMcKenzie's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78065202/why-does-creating-a-pointer-to-a-node-on-the-stack-cause-my-linked-list-display/78065312?noredirect=1#comment137623389_78065202), where the output in that case was `2082743487 1224904152` instead. I hope this is more clear now, but please let me know if I can try to explain anything else.